# Samsung Galaxy: Unlock gone haywire

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sim-unlocking

I applied the procedure to unlock a Samsung Galaxy S3 on a Samsung Galaxy Express I437.  It went through smoothly, and but the phone was not unlocked.  Instead, it gives me the error message "Phone not allowed MM#6" after I inserted a foreign SIM card.  The procedure is reproduced below:

[1] UMTS
[1] Debug Screen
[8] Phone Control
[6] Network Lock
Options [3]Perso SHA256 OFF
(after choosing this option, wait about 30 seconds, then go back one step by pressing the Menu button then select Back, now you are in
[6] Network Lock then choose
[4] NW Lock NV Data INITIALLIZ ..... wait for a minute then reboot your phone

Since this didn't work, I tried reverting NW LOCK back to the old setting.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  The unlock screen doesn't come up anymore.  And I have no other way to enter an unlock code.  Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Million thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the procedure worked.  The IMEI is blacklisted by the foreign network at the time of the test.